# How to exclude a spring context of a project which depends on another project while testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have two Java projects, "A" and "B", and B has a Maven dependency on A. I started creating tests for B, but when I try to run the tests it wont work.
 The error is that when testing B my test uses the spring context of A.

Any idea of how can I exclude the A context from the tests of B?
I'm using this to set the context of the tests from B

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {BTestContext.class})
```

I tried to use exclude filters in BTestContext but that didnt work.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.b"}, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = ABeanConfig.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation below states that you can specify a customerContextLoader or customContextInitializer for the @ContextConfiguration annotation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations

One suggestion would then be to create a custom ContextLoader.

For annotation based config looks like you might want to override 1 or more methods in the following:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/AnnotationConfigContextLoader.html